# jsf Command button not working in an include Jsp

Tags: jsf

I have a jsp page which has dynamic includes. each dynamic include invoke its own backing bean and works fine with dataTables and reading data from backing bean, But i am facing problems with the command button. when i click command button, the control is not being transferred to the bean and it not navigating to the next page as it is not hitting the onclick method.

any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have <h:messages> tag on the page? There might be validation error stopping the method invocation.

Comment: there is no <h:messages> tag on top of the include page but there is a <h:messages> tag on top of the parent jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that the value of the dynamic bean property behind `<jsp:include page>` is exactly the same during the form submit as it was during displaying the page with the form. So if it's obtained from a request scoped bean, then you need to ensure that the property is set during its (post)construction as well based on some request parameter which you could set as a managed property or obtain from `ExternalContext#getRequestParameterMap()`. An alternative is to put the bean in the session scope, but this won't work very well when the enduser has the same page open in multiple browser windows/tabs in the same session.

Comment: thanks for the reply Bauke, but i did not understand your second point which is <h:form> should be outside the <ui:include>.

Comment: This is explained in second "See also" question link. If you need the `<h:form>` to be inside `<ui:include>` anyway, then apply the solution which is posted in the answer of that question. Or use PrimeFaces 3.x, they have fixed this issue in their own core ajax engine.

Comment: the jsp page contains <odc:tabbedPanel> and in this tabbed panel every tab is an include page. so when i view the source of the page it is genrating an automatic form at <odc: tabbedpanel>. i made sure that every page is maintained in a <f:Subview>. so still do you want me to use the above approach, even for this tabbed panel

Comment: Wait.. Are you using JSF 1.x or 2.x? I assumed JSF 2.x all the time as JSF 1.x was ended at December 2009.

Comment: I guess there is no view scope for the backing bean in jsf 1.2

Comment: ok do you any more suggestions about this problem, this is really important for me.

Comment: when i changed the scope of the bean to session, even then its not working. anyways thank you very much for the help. you did help a lot of people by answering many questions. this is taking too long so we might update our version to JSF 2 or change the design on where exactly to place the button and we might also remove this tabbed approach.